# Heatmap-no data vs Zero

Tags: heat-map, color, download, color-ramp, qgis-3

I am new to QGIS. I am working on creating heat map of bird diversity(data downloaded from ebird.org). The issue I face is that how to differentiate between:

1. There areas where data is not available (bird surveys haven't happened)
2. Bird survey has happened but a particular bird species is absent at that area

When create a heatmap of the particular bird species with QGIS 3.2.3(windows), the map interprets both situations as same, which is not correct. **In the image attached, the white areas are either with no data or places where there are no kingfishers found. I want to color code them differently.**

How can I find a way to overcome this?
[image: heat map of number of species of Kingfisher in India]

Answer (score 1):

The approach that you can take is to either assign a different value within the attribute table from 1 to either category to allow you to distinguish between the scenarios you've mentioned. Or you can select the feature of interest and create a new dataset and now you will have two different datasets which you can stylize and categorize independently.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the approach that the EBird range map does - use a color to indicate where a checklist was submitted, but no sighting of the species, and use no color to indicate where no checklists/no species were seen:

[image]

So in your case, I would keep the white to indicate ZERO, but would fill in the other areas in your density raster with a grey color to indicate 'no data submitted' or something to that effect.